# Как построить кратчайшую цепочку связанных объектов

Tags: java, алгоритм

> Входные данные:
> `HashMap`, наполненный объектами.
> Каждый объект `Aspect` состоит из ключа (`String`, имя объекта) и двух объектов этого же класса (т.е. каждый объект состоит из двух объектов, кроме 6 базовых объектов, у которых поля подобъектов равны `null`).
>
> Задание: построить алгоритм, который при введении двух объектов будет выводить самую короткую цепочку объектов, объединяющих эти два объекта.

Содержимое класса:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Vampirenostra on 16.01.2017.
 */
public class Aspect
{
    private String name;
    private Aspect con1;
    private Aspect con2;

    public static ArrayList<Aspect> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static HashMap<String,Aspect> aspects = new HashMap<>();

    Aspect (String name, Aspect con1,Aspect con2){this.name=name;this.con1=con1;this.con2=con2;}
    Aspect(String name){this.name=name;}

    public String toString()
    {
        if (java.util.Objects.equals(con1, null))return name;
        else return name+" "+con1+" "+con2+" ";
    }

    public static void addAspects()
    {
        aspects.put("Aer",          new Aspect("Aer"));
        aspects.put("Terra",        new Aspect("Terra"));
        aspects.put("Aqua",         new Aspect("Aqua"));
        aspects.put("Ignis",        new Aspect("Ignis"));
        aspects.put("Ordo",         new Aspect("Ordo"));
        aspects.put("Perditio",     new Aspect("Perditio"));
        aspects.put("Lux",          new Aspect("Lux",       aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Ignis")));
        aspects.put("Motus",        new Aspect("Motus",     aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Ordo")));
        aspects.put("Gelum",        new Aspect("Gelum",     aspects.get("Ignis"),   aspects.get("Perditio")));
        aspects.put("Victus",       new Aspect("Victus",    aspects.get("Terra"),   aspects.get("Aqua")));
        aspects.put("Tempestas",    new Aspect("Tempestas", aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Aqua")));
        aspects.put("Vacuos",       new Aspect("Vacuos",    aspects.get("Perditio"),aspects.get("Aer")));
        aspects.put("Potentia",     new Aspect("Potentia",  aspects.get("Ignis"),   aspects.get("Ordo")));
        aspects.put("Viterus",      new Aspect("Viterus",   aspects.get("Ordo"),    aspects.get("Terra")));
        aspects.put("Permutatio",   new Aspect("Permutatio",aspects.get("Perditio"),aspects.get("Ordo")));
        aspects.put("Venenum",      new Aspect("Venenum",   aspects.get("Aqua"),    aspects.get("Perditio")));
        aspects.put("Fames",        new Aspect("Fames",     aspects.get("Vacuos"),  aspects.get("Victus")));
        aspects.put("Bestia",       new Aspect("Bestia",    aspects.get("Victus"),  aspects.get("Motus")));
        aspects.put("Metallum",     new Aspect("Metallum",  aspects.get("Terra"),   aspects.get("Viterus")));
        aspects.put("Herba",        new Aspect("Herba",     aspects.get("Terra"),   aspects.get("Victus")));
        aspects.put("Sano",         new Aspect("Sano",      aspects.get("Victus"),  aspects.get("Ordo")));
        aspects.put("Mortuus",      new Aspect("Mortuus",   aspects.get("Victus"),  aspects.get("Perditio")));
        aspects.put("Praecantatio", new Aspect("Praecantatio",aspects.get("Vacuos"),aspects.get("Potentia")));
        aspects.put("Limus",        new Aspect("Limus",     aspects.get("Aqua"),    aspects.get("Victus")));
        aspects.put("Iter",         new Aspect("Iter",      aspects.get("Terra"),   aspects.get("Motus")));
        aspects.put("Tenebrae",     new Aspect("Tenebrae",  aspects.get("Lux"),     aspects.get("Vacuos")));
        aspects.put("Volatus",      new Aspect("Volatus",   aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Motus")));
        aspects.put("Vinculum",     new Aspect("Vinculum",  aspects.get("Perditio"),aspects.get("Motus")));
        aspects.put("Spiritus",     new Aspect("Spiritus",  aspects.get("Victus"),  aspects.get("Mortuus")));
        aspects.put("Auram",        new Aspect("Auram",     aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Praecantatio")));
        aspects.put("Exanimis",     new Aspect("Exanimis",  aspects.get("Mortuus"), aspects.get("Motus")));
        aspects.put("Vitium",       new Aspect("Vitium",    aspects.get("Perditio"),aspects.get("Praecantatio")));
        aspects.put("Corpus",       new Aspect("Corpus",    aspects.get("Bestia"),  aspects.get("Mortuus")));
        aspects.put("Alienis",      new Aspect("Alienis",   aspects.get("Tenebrae"),aspects.get("Vacuos")));
        aspects.put("Sensus",       new Aspect("Sensus",    aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Spiritus")));
        aspects.put("Cognitio",     new Aspect("Cognitio",  aspects.get("Ignis"),   aspects.get("Spiritus")));
        aspects.put("Arbor",        new Aspect("Arbor",     aspects.get("Aer"),     aspects.get("Herba")));
        aspects.put("Humanus",      new Aspect("Humanus",   aspects.get("Cognitio"),aspects.get("Bestia")));
        aspects.put("Messis",       new Aspect("Messis",    aspects.get("Humanus"), aspects.get("Herba")));
        aspects.put("Lucrum",       new Aspect("Lucrum",    aspects.get("Humanus"), aspects.get("Fames")));
        aspects.put("Instrumentum", new Aspect("Instrumentum",aspects.get("Humanus"),aspects.get("Ordo")));
        aspects.put("Perfodio",     new Aspect("Perfodio",  aspects.get("Humaus"),  aspects.get("Terra")));
        aspects.put("Fabrico",      new Aspect("Fabrico",   aspects.get("Humanus"), aspects.get("Instrumentum")));
        aspects.put("Machina",      new Aspect("Machina",   aspects.get("Motus"),   aspects.get("Instrumentum")));
        aspects.put("Pannus",       new Aspect("Pannus",    aspects.get("Bestia"),  aspects.get("Instrumentum")));
        aspects.put("Tutamen",      new Aspect("Tutamen",   aspects.get("Terra"),   aspects.get("Instrumentum")));
        aspects.put("Telum",        new Aspect("Telum",     aspects.get("Ignis"),   aspects.get("Instrumentum")));
        aspects.put("Meto",         new Aspect("Meto",      aspects.get("Messis"),  aspects.get("Instrumentum")));


    }

    public static String input() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return br.readLine();
    }

    public static boolean check(String x){return aspects.containsKey(x);}

    public static ArrayList<Aspect> upList (String asp)
    {
        ArrayList<Aspect> upList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Aspect aspect : aspects.values())
        {if (aspect.con1!=null&&(aspect.con1.name.equals(asp)||aspect.con2.name.equals(asp))) {upList.add(aspect);}}
        return upList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Aspect> downList(String asp)
    {
        ArrayList<Aspect> downList = new ArrayList<>();
        downList.add(aspects.get(asp).con1); downList.add(aspects.get(asp).con2);
        return downList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> same()
    {
        ArrayList<String> same = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Aspect> list = upList(Main.asp1);
        String tmp = list.toString();
        tmp=tmp.replaceAll(",","");tmp=tmp.replaceAll("]","");tmp=tmp.replaceAll("\\[" ,"");
        while (tmp.contains("  ")){tmp=tmp.replaceAll("  "," ");}
        if(tmp.endsWith(" ")){tmp=tmp.trim();}
        String[] tmp1 = tmp.split(" ");

        ArrayList<String> one = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(one, tmp1);

        list = upList(Main.asp2);
        tmp = list.toString();
        tmp=tmp.replaceAll(",","");tmp=tmp.replaceAll("]","");tmp=tmp.replaceAll("\\[" ,"");
        while (tmp.contains("  ")){tmp=tmp.replaceAll("  "," ");}
        if(tmp.endsWith(" ")){tmp=tmp.trim();}
        tmp1 = tmp.split(" ");

        ArrayList<String> two = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(two, tmp1);
        System.out.println(one.size()+" "+two.size());

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String text:one) {map.put(text,null);}
        one=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String text:map.keySet()) {one.add(text);}
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String text:two) {map.put(text,null);}
        two=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String text:map.keySet()) {two.add(text);same.add(text);}


        same.retainAll(one);

        return same;
    }


    public static void listPrint (ArrayList <Aspect> list)
    {
        for (Aspect aspect : list) {System.out.println(aspect);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Уточните, в чем должна заключаться помощь?

Comment: 1. Нужен алгоритм поиска цепочки взаимосвязанных объектов. 2. Эти цепочки сохранять в допустим List для последующей отбраковки по size().

Comment: Не стоит толкать несколько команд и фигурные скобки в одну строку. Это делает код нечитабельным. Код `for (String text:map.keySet()) {two.add(text);same.add(text);}` должен занимать 5 (4, если ставить `{` на той же строке) строк, а не одну.

Answer (score 0):

Можно составить список связей между объектами (граф, вершинами которого являются `Aspect`-ы, а рёбрами - связи между ними), после чего воспользоваться поиском в ширину:

```
public static ArrayList<Aspect> findShortestWay(Aspect first, Aspect second)
{
    //построение связей
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Aspect>> aspectNameToRelatedAspects = new HashMap<>();
    for (Aspect aspect : aspects.values())
    {
        ArrayList<Aspect> relatedAspects = new ArrayList<>();
        if (aspect.con1 != null)
        {
            relatedAspects.add(aspect.con1);
        }
        if (aspect.con2 != null)
        {
            relatedAspects.add(aspect.con2);
        }
        for (Aspect otherAspect : aspects.values())
        {
            if (aspect.equals(otherAspect) || otherAspect.equals(aspect.con1) || otherAspect.equals(aspect.con2))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (aspect.equals(otherAspect.con1) || aspect.equals(otherAspect.con2))
            {
                relatedAspects.add(otherAspect);
            }
        }
        aspectNameToRelatedAspects.put(aspect.name, relatedAspects);
    }

    //поиск в ширину
    HashMap<String, Aspect> aspectNameToPreviousAspect = new HashMap<>();
    aspectNameToPreviousAspect.put(first.name, first);
    ArrayList<Aspect> queue = new ArrayList<>();
    queue.add(first);
    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        Aspect aspect = queue.remove(0);
        if (aspect.equals(second))
        {
            break;
        }
        ArrayList<Aspect> relatedAspects = aspectNameToRelatedAspects.get(aspect.name);
        for (Aspect relatedAspect : relatedAspects)
        {
            if (!aspectNameToPreviousAspect.containsKey(relatedAspect.name))
            {
                queue.add(relatedAspect);
                aspectNameToPreviousAspect.put(relatedAspect.name, aspect);
            }
        }
    }

    //построение цепочки связей
    ArrayList<Aspect> way = null;
    if (aspectNameToPreviousAspect.containsKey(second.name))
    {
        way = new ArrayList<>();
        Aspect previousAspect = second;
        do
        {
            way.add(previousAspect);
            previousAspect = aspectNameToPreviousAspect.get(previousAspect.name);
        }
        while (!previousAspect.equals(first));
        way.add(first);
        Collections.reverse(way);
    }
    return way;
}

private boolean equals(Aspect aspect)
{
    return aspect != null && name.equals(aspect.name);
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    String con1Name = (con1 != null) ? con1.name : "null";
    String con2Name = (con2 != null) ? con2.name : "null";
    return name + " -> " + con1Name + " " + con2Name;
}
```

И использование:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Aspect.addAspects();
    ArrayList<Aspect> way = Aspect.findShortestWay(Aspect.aspects.get("Aer"), Aspect.aspects.get("Aqua"));
    if (way == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Связи нет");
    }
    else
    {
        for (Aspect aspect : way)
        {
            System.out.println(aspect);
        }
    }
}
```